# How to keep search keyword and pagenation when router back from detail page to list page in vue with vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How to keep search keyword and pagenation when router back from detail page to list page in vue with vue router?

Now, it doesn't. I didn't have such a code so I need to modify it

For Example, the case that user is in list page page-number 3, and search Keyword with memberName like "john", and click to link in detail, at this time I need to keep data this page number and "john" when user router back from detail.

thank you for replying my question

Comment: store them in Vuex.

Comment: there is also Pinia

Comment: Another way is that, when moving to detail page store the keyword and number in query params of router and then when moving back to the list page, auto-fill the data.